# Service worker - get push data from my server

Tags: service-worker

I'm using my server to send web notifications and display them using service worker in my client.

To send the notification. i'm using [this php library](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php)

To receive them, i'm using the following code:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to send extra information such as the message title and body to my push event. I tried to add payload attribute when sending a message from my server, but the event data is empty:

[image]

Any idea what's wrong / How I can receive information sent by my server?

Answer (score 0):

First use [web push](https://github.com/zaru/webpush) to generate a public key and private key.

then use the public key to register your service worker.

```
function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
  const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
  const base64 = (base64String + padding)
    .replace(/\-/g, '+')
    .replace(/_/g, '/');

  const rawData = window.atob(base64);
  const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
    outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return outputArray;
}




     navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js',{scope: '/'})
    .then(function(swReg) {

      swRegistration = swReg;

const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
     swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
          userVisibleOnly: true,
          applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
        })
    })
```

which should give you a end_point - p256dh - auth.

Use this to send the notification with web push.

```
Webpush.payload_send(
                    endpoint: registration_token["endpoint"],
                    message: JSON.generate(data),
                    p256dh: registration_token["keys"]["p256dh"],
                    auth: registration_token["keys"]["auth"],
                        vapid: {
                                public_key: public_key,
                                private_key: private_key
                })
```